# How to determine the type of a child object from the SQLAlchemy model?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following SQLAlchemy model:

```
class PersonConsent(ModelAbstract):
    __tablename__ = "personConsent"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    patientId = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("person.id"))
    authorizedPersonId = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("person.id"))
    attachmentId = db.Column(db.Integer)

    # Additional models
    authorizedPerson = db.relationship("Person", foreign_keys=[authorizedPersonId])
    consents = db.relationship("PersonConsentType", 
                secondary=personConsentToTypeMap,
                primaryjoin=id==personConsentToTypeMap.c.consentId,
                secondaryjoin=PersonConsentType.id==personConsentToTypeMap.c.consentTypeId)
```

**Given just the PersonConsent model how do I determine the model of items that make up the `consents` field?**

For example, something like

`type(PersonConsent.consents) == PersonConsentType`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `inspect` function and follow the correct attributes to get the target model for a relationship.

```
from sqlalchemy import inspect

mapper = inspect(PersonConsent)
property = mapper.relationships['consents']
target = property.mapper.class_

assert target is PersonConsentType
```

You can technically get to this by doing `PersonConsent.consents.property.mapper.class_`, but it's less general.  You could use the inspection above to, for example, loop over *all* the relationships, even if you don't know their names.